# Unable to run WebDriverIo tutorial

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io, geckodriver

I'm trying to follow the WebDriverIo tutorial at http://webdriver.io/guide.html .

After setting up the Selenium server, when I try executing the test node script (step 7 in the tutorial), selenium warns me of some errors (see screenshot for full log), and I don't get any output returned.

Steps to reproduce:

I start the Selenium server
[image]

When I try running the node script, this happens (clock to zoom):
[image]

[image]

At this point a Firefox window opens automatically, and remains blank.

I'm running Firefox v52 and Selenium 3.0.1. I downloaded Geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Any obvious thing that I'm missing? I'm very new to Selenium and browser automation, forgive the generic input :)

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what is a content of `test-js` file?

Comment: test.js initializes a new instance of Webriverio, sets up its options, requests a page and console.logs its title. At the current state, Selenium seems to fail when attemtping to request the page. Please have a look at the very short tutorial [here](http://webdriver.io/guide.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have been here to get your Windows release of gecko driver : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases, you may have miss this message :

> "**IMPORTANT**: If you use geckodriver with Selenium, you must upgrade to
>   Selenium 3.3 since this release aligns HTTP responses with the
>   WebDriver standard."

(I can see you are in v3.0.1).

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot for the help